# Database Lock error Occurs while Running service

Tags: android, service

I have a service which will update the Sqllite database with data at each 10 minute with the help of service.I have Opened a database connetion and closed the connection when data got updated.

In my application I have differnt pages where database updation took place.I have also Opened a database connetion and closed the connection each and every pages for data updation.

The Problem is that While the service is running I am not Able to Update the data to sqlite throught my application when conncetion opened in the service.

Is there any way to run data base updation simuntanously using service and application.

Will any one help with samples.

I am calling a function in my sevice as given below (code)

```
public class service_helper extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "Service";
    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
    private service_updator serviceUpdator;
    private int NOTIFICATION = 1;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();


        serviceUpdator = new service_updator(this);
        dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        startService() ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        timer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

     private void startService()     
     {                   
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 250000);   
         }    
     private class mainTask extends TimerTask    
     {         
         public void run()    
         {           
             try {
                serviceUpdator.UploadData();
                Log.d(TAG, "Service");
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
             }    
         } 



    private Runnable threadBody = new Runnable() {


             public void run() {

            try {

                serviceUpdator.UploadData();

                Log.d(TAG, "Service");
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                            }

        }




    };


    }

UploadData() Function Code

    dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this.context);
            dbAdapter.open();
            Long transactionType = null;
            String transactionData = null;
            String sql = "Select * from tblTransaction where PKTransaction >?";
            Cursor cursorTransaction = dbAdapter.ExecuteRawQuery(sql, "-1");
            cursorTransaction.moveToFirst();
            dbAdapter.close();

                  for (int i = 0; i < cursorTransaction.getCount(); i++) {
                  }

    dbAdapter.close();

Application Code

    private void SaveSortOrder() throws Exception {
            try {
                String server1IPAddress = "";
                String server2IPAddress = "";
                String deviceId = "";

                Cursor cursorTransaction;
                Cursor cursorAdmin;

                DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
                DataXmlExporter dataXmlExporter;
                admin_helper adminhelper;
                Date date = new Date();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                String RevisedEstimatedDate = sdf.format(date);

                adminhelper = new admin_helper(this);
                cursorAdmin = adminhelper.GetAdminDetails();
                if (cursorAdmin.moveToFirst())
                    server1IPAddress = cursorAdmin.getString(cursorAdmin
                            .getColumnIndex("RemoteServer1IPAddress"));
                server2IPAddress = cursorAdmin.getString(cursorAdmin
                        .getColumnIndex("RemoteServer2IPAddress"));
                deviceId = cursorAdmin.getString(cursorAdmin
                        .getColumnIndex("DeviceID"));
                cursorAdmin.close();

                ContentValues initialSortOrder = new ContentValues();
                ContentValues initialTransaction = new ContentValues();
                for (int i = 0; i < ListSortOrder.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {

                    HashMap result = (HashMap) ListSortOrder.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    View vListSortOrder;
                    vListSortOrder = ListSortOrder.getChildAt(i);

                    TextView Sort_DeliveryOrder = (TextView) vListSortOrder
                            .findViewById(R.id.et_Sort_Order);

                    initialSortOrder.put("DeliveryOrder", Sort_DeliveryOrder
                            .getText().toString());
                    dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
                    dbAdapter.open();

                    dbAdapter.BeginTransaction();
                    dbAdapter.UpdateRecord("tblDelivery", initialSortOrder,
                            "PKDelivery" + "="
                                    + result.get("Sort_PKDelivery").toString(),
                            null);

                    dataXmlExporter = new DataXmlExporter(this);
                    dataXmlExporter.StartDataSet();

                    String sqlTransaction = "Select 5 as TransactionType,'Update Delivery Order' as Description,'"
                            + result.get("Sort_PKDelivery").toString()
                            + "' as FKDelivery, "
                            + " deviceId as DeviceID ,'"
                            + Sort_DeliveryOrder.getText().toString()
                            + "' as DeliveryOrder ,date() as TransactionUploadDate,time() as TransactionUploadTime from tblAdmin where PKAdmin > ?";

                    cursorTransaction = dbAdapter.ExecuteRawQuery(sqlTransaction,
                            "-1");
                    dataXmlExporter.AddRowandColumns(cursorTransaction,
                            "Transaction");
                    String XMLTransactionData = dataXmlExporter.EndDataSet();

                    try {

                        if ((server1IPAddress != "") && (server2IPAddress != "")) {
                            try {
                                if (server1IPAddress != "") {
                                    InsertUploadedTrancasctionDetails(
                                            server1IPAddress, deviceId,
                                            XMLTransactionData);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception exception) {

                                if ((server1IPAddress != server2IPAddress)
                                        && (server2IPAddress != "")) {
                                    InsertUploadedTrancasctionDetails(
                                            server2IPAddress, deviceId,
                                            XMLTransactionData);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception exception) {

                        initialTransaction
                                .put("ReceivedDate", RevisedEstimatedDate);
                        initialTransaction.put("TransactionData",
                                XMLTransactionData);

                        dbAdapter.InsertRecord("tblTransaction", "",
                                initialTransaction);

                    }

                    dbAdapter.SetSucessfulTransaction();
                    dbAdapter.EndTransaction();
                    dbAdapter.close();

                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a similar application who's service runs every 5 minutes and I don't have an issue.  You're SQLiteHelper class should be handling the various requests without issue.  Can you please post the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when moving to Honeycomb it started throwing SQLiteDatabaseLockedException I sorted it by putting a content provider over my database and then Android handles all the threading issues. You can try find the threading problem if you want of course but that would definitely fix it :)